# Ecosystem Control Theory

Tags: ecology, theoretical-biology, computational-model, ecosystem

I've used [EcoNet online tool](http://eco.engr.uga.edu/index.html) to analyze an ecosystem. You can run the default model by pressing "run model" in order to follow my question.
Among the extended results there are 2 'Control Matrix' but unfortunately they don't state the source for the calculations in [their documentation](http://eco.engr.uga.edu/DOC/econet4.html#utility). In the documentation, right below Utility Analysis, there's a blank paragraph intended for Control Analysis.
I'm looking for someone that knows some articles explaining the math behind those matrixes and also their interpretation.
I'd be really glad if you could help me.